# How to use an XML tag inside a DIV as a JQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0dapo32a/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="test1">
<office1><a title="98 Tuvalu road" href="/IDD=1603">98 Tuvalu road</a></office1>
</div>
<div class="test1">
<office2><a title="900 Bleek Ave" href="/IDD=23">900 Bleek Ave</a></office2>
</div>
<div class="test1">
<office3><a title="73 Wabash Street" href="/IDD=3">73 Wabash Street</a></office3>
</div>
```

How can I edit the JQuery to append anchor text based on criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector is looking for direct children of `.test1` by using `>`.

Change to

```
$(".test1  a");//match any `a` that is descendant of class `test1`
```

And it works fine

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/0dapo32a/2/)**</kbd>

Comment: Silly me. I forgot to include the `.` for the class selector :/

Answer (score 1):

The same way you use any other tag name

```
$(".test1 office1 a")
```

If you are wanting to target all 3 office tags you will need to do it three times and separate them by a comma

```
$(".test1 office1 a,.test1 office2 a,.test1 office3 a")
```

Or just remove the child selector you were using

```
$(".test1 a")
```

Though note the last one will select any `a` tag that is within `.test1`

Answer (score 1):

jQuery selector with `>` looks for direct children of the `.test1` class. Change it to `$(".test1  a")` to match all `a` that are descendant of that class:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test1">
<office1><a title="98 Tuvalu road" href="/IDD=1603">98 Tuvalu road</a></office1>
</div>
<div class="test1">
<office2><a title="900 Bleek Ave" href="/IDD=23">900 Bleek Ave</a></office2>
</div>
<div class="test1">
<office3><a title="73 Wabash Street" href="/IDD=3">73 Wabash Street</a></office3>
</div>
<script>
var vCityState = new Array("| Darien CT", "| Greenwich CT");

$(".test1 a").text(function (index, oldText) {
    if (oldText.indexOf("900") > -1) {
     return oldText + vCityState[0];
    }
    if (oldText.indexOf("Wabash") > -1) {
     return oldText + vCityState[1];
    }
});  
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery doesn't care if the tag is XML or anything as it looks for it based on the string.

so you can use:

```
$("div office1").css("backgroundColor","red");

//or
$("div office1").append('<a href="http://google.com">google</a>');
```